# Scalable django app, should message queue be located on load balancer or app server?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, django, gunicorn

I've just architected my first scalable backend for a django app, however I put the message queue service (RabbitMQ) on the load balancer machine. I was able to siege some of my API routes with up to 500 concurrent users without a serious time deficit but I'm wondering if I'd have any better performance by putting the MQ service somewhere else.

My setup right now:

app requests > load balancer (nginx, rabbitmq) > workers, 2 in use (gunicorn/celery) > db (postgres)

So I have currently 4 AWS EC2 instances (all m3.medium) connected up in a VPC doing all this for me. It wouldn't make much sense to do rabbit on the worker nodes so I'm just trying to get an idea of what people do.

I'm also curious about how to best configure gunicorn but from my searching it doesn't seem like there's a whole lot to mess with other than number/type of actual workers. Which for my AWS EC2 instance (m3.medium) is only 3/synchronous (got worse performance using async workers).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your MQ should be located on a separate instance(s) so it can be scaled independently of either your application servers or load balancer. This is also makes maintenance easer (you can swap out your load balancer instance without having to migrate your existing queue for example) and it's better for security to have them isolated (your LB needs public access whereas your MQ doesn't).

It's also worth pointing out that AWS is very much oriented towards separating which can be managed efficiently with large economies of scale from what is unique to your application and delegating what they like to call "undifferentiated heavy lifting" to managed AWS services. For example it's common on AWS to use either SQS or a Redis based MQ on ElastiCache, which both support a HA architecture out of the box (EC via Multi-AZ). Likewise you could delegate your LB to ELB, freeing you to focus on optimising your application and possibly DB servers (if RDS doesn't suit your needs, I'm not sure what the Postgres situation is) servers.

Comment: I was trying to stay focused on building it out without relying too heavily on AWS products. I'd like to try them eventually, but I also would like to do most of this myself. As far as the Postgres is concerned, I wouldn't mind using RDS but I'd like to figure out how to distribute it myself...haven't found much in the way of tutorials on this though.